# Can I recover filenames from a failed RAID0 (Linux Debian 5.0.8)

Tags: raid, mdadm, md

Linux Debian version 5.0.8 is running on my Iomega NAS and it has a RAID0 array of four 3TB disks that failed on the "third" disk.

I am aware of the non-redundancy of RAID0 but I would like to recover the filenames from that RAID0. If I could recover some data it would be a bonus.

where sda1, sdb1, sdc1 and sdd1 should be the 4 RAID devices.

What could be my next step?

I thank you for your time

Here is the output from the command:

```
fdisk -l
=============================================
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sda: 3000.5 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x03afffbe

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sda1 1 267350 2147483647+ ee EFI GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sdb: 3000.5 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x142a889c

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdb1 1 267350 2147483647+ ee EFI GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sdc: 3000.5 GB, 3000592982016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 364801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3daebd50

Device Boot Start End Blocks Id System
/dev/sdc1 1 267350 2147483647+ ee EFI GPT

Disk /dev/md0: 21.4 GB, 21484339200 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 5245200 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Here is the output from the command:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/sd[abcd]1
=============================================
/dev/sda1:
Magic : a92b4efc
Version : 00.90.00
UUID : 7d247a6e:7b5d46c8:f52d9c89:db304b21
Creation Time : Mon Apr 23 19:55:36 2012
Raid Level : raid1
Used Dev Size : 20980800 (20.01 GiB 21.48 GB)
Array Size : 20980800 (20.01 GiB 21.48 GB)
Raid Devices : 4
Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

Update Time : Mon Jun 27 21:12:23 2016
      State : clean
Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
Failed Devices : 1
Spare Devices : 0
Checksum : 1a57db60 - correct
Events : 164275

  Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this 0 8 1 0 active sync /dev/sda1

0 0 8 1 0 active sync /dev/sda1
1 1 8 17 1 active sync /dev/sdb1
2 2 0 0 2 faulty removed
3 3 8 33 3 active sync /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdb1:
Magic : a92b4efc
Version : 00.90.00
UUID : 7d247a6e:7b5d46c8:f52d9c89:db304b21
Creation Time : Mon Apr 23 19:55:36 2012
Raid Level : raid1
Used Dev Size : 20980800 (20.01 GiB 21.48 GB)
Array Size : 20980800 (20.01 GiB 21.48 GB)
Raid Devices : 4
Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

Update Time : Mon Jun 27 21:12:23 2016
      State : clean
Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
Failed Devices : 1
Spare Devices : 0
Checksum : 1a57db72 - correct
Events : 164275

  Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this 1 8 17 1 active sync /dev/sdb1

0 0 8 1 0 active sync /dev/sda1
1 1 8 17 1 active sync /dev/sdb1
2 2 0 0 2 faulty removed
3 3 8 33 3 active sync /dev/sdc1
/dev/sdc1:
Magic : a92b4efc
Version : 00.90.00
UUID : 7d247a6e:7b5d46c8:f52d9c89:db304b21
Creation Time : Mon Apr 23 19:55:36 2012
Raid Level : raid1
Used Dev Size : 20980800 (20.01 GiB 21.48 GB)
Array Size : 20980800 (20.01 GiB 21.48 GB)
Raid Devices : 4
Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

Update Time : Mon Jun 27 21:12:23 2016
      State : clean
Active Devices : 3
Working Devices : 3
Failed Devices : 1
Spare Devices : 0
Checksum : 1a57db86 - correct
Events : 164275

  Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this 3 8 33 3 active sync /dev/sdc1

0 0 8 1 0 active sync /dev/sda1
1 1 8 17 1 active sync /dev/sdb1
2 2 0 0 2 faulty removed
3 3 8 33 3 active sync /dev/sdc1
=============================================
```

Comment: Debian 5? Wow, that's rather old ([early 2009](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Debian_releases#Debian_5.0_.28Lenny.29)). First, do you have enough storage space elsewhere to create a copy of the remaining drives such that you can work on the copy rather than the original? (That would ensure that any mistakes don't further degrade your data.) Also, try `apropos ext2`; `debugfs`, `dumpe2fs` and `e2image` look *vaguely* useful.

Comment: You say raid0 but your `mdadm --examine` output says raid1.  With raid1 or raid10, your data is OK - for safety, just replace the failed drive and resync the raid array.  with raid0 you would have little or no hope of recovering your data.  If it was a linear-append raid0, you would have lost only the data on the failed drive.  If it was a (far more common) striped raid0 you would have lost everything on all drives.  raid0 is ONLY suitable for data you a) don't care about AND b) have a backup that's regularly updated AND c) where you really need the read & write bandwidth of multiple drives.

Comment: please add the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` and `blkid` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Losing any member of RAID 0 array makes any file extraction almost impossible as you are missing a quarter of all the information that was previously stored, including the `superblocks` and directories.

If you have very important text documents, a text extraction could be done to retrieve 3 quarters of what you had, which could actually be automated by a simple program that would combine the chunks for the 3 partitions based on their chunk size.

Making anything useful with that information is more typical of police and spy agencies because of the effort needed to get the information, especially considering that it is incomplete.